# Emacs define-key, Viper-mode key binding

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, viper, viper-mode, colemak

I'm trying to learn emacs, getting vi custom key bindings.

Using Viper-mode, what is the correct way to re-bind a key? (I'm using [Colemak keyboard layout](http://colemak.com/)(instead of qwerty) so have to change things like n->j) But would like it to work in viper-mode.

From this key binding guide on GNU.org:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/viper/Key-Bindings.html

It says the command to put in your .viper file is:

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-v" 'scroll-down)
```

It doesn't work for me... in fact not sure I even have the function "define-key"...

```
M-x define-key [No match]
```

I'm not sure if 'define-key' is available on my version of emacs?

This works, but not in viper-mode

```
(global-set-key "n" "j")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. This is my first day using Emacs, to it's a pain getting Colemak & Viper-mode to work properly.

Thank for any help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully some useful answers here:

First, having that line in the `.viper` works for me.  Note that the `viper-vi-global-user-map` applies when you're in *command* mode, not insert mode.

Secondly, `define-key` isn't a command, it's a regular function, which just means that it cannot be called using <kbd>M-x</kbd>.  See this [Emacs wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveFunction) for a little more detail on that distinction.  But that was a good attempt.

Third, the `global-set-key` *is* a command, you could have tried making a change using <kbd>M-x global-set-key</kbd>.  But, that sets the key in the [current global map](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html), which isn't the same as `viper-vi-global-user-map`.  Viper-mode uses a bunch of different keymaps to make Emacs behave like vi, but all of the maps are overlaid on top of the global map.

I'm guessing that you found that <kbd>C-v</kbd> wasn't bound like you want when you're in *insert* mode.  And that can be solved by adding this to your `.viper`:

```
(define-key viper-insert-global-user-map "\C-v" 'scroll-down)
```

Lastly, `scroll-down` may not be what you want.  The `down` refers to the text moving down (given the perspective of a fixed window).  <kbd>C-v</kbd> is generally bound to `'scroll-up`.  But,maybe it is exactly what you want.

*Caveat:* I'm not a viper-mode user, I don't even know how to use vi.  So my terminology may be off.  But I find the challenge of changing things in viper-mode very interesting.

*Edited to add*

From your comment it sounds like you want <kbd>n</kbd> to be the same as what <kbd>j</kbd> is bound to by default.  Try adding this:

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "n" 'viper-next-line)
```

In "normal" mode I did <kbd>M-x describe-key j</kbd>, which told me that <kbd>j</kbd> is bound to `'viper-next-line`, and the above line will bind <kbd>n</kbd> to the same routine.  Repeat for the rest of the bindings you want to shift around.

Comment: Hey Trey, thanks for the detailed response. :)  When you said "command mode" do you mean the opposite of insert mode? Vim calls this normal mode. Actually I wanted it to work in normal-mode (movement-mode)?

Comment: I should of had a more realistic 'define-key' example, actually I wanted to turn "n" into "j" in normal/movement mode. But keep "n" as "n" in insert mode. (This is because "j" as well as "h,k,l" is part of VIM movement controls which has to be turned into "n,h,e,i" Colemak's equivalent)

Comment: @Quang see the latest addition.

Comment: Awesome! thank you. Works as expected. :) Potentially migrating from vim to Emacs is daunting.  I'll be sure to update the basics keybindings of how to get emacs to work with viper+colemak to anyone who's interested. Thanks again Trey.

Answer (score 1):

in modern times evil-mode is the vim emulation layer for emacs, and to tweak it for colemak, my https://github.com/wbolster/evil-colemak-basics package helps a lot.